# SSIS 2005 - how to skip rows from input flat file programmatically

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I need to import a .csv file into a SQL table.

The  input file looks like:

```
gru,212,BNP10H,bnp10h,1,01,Gestore 01
limGru,2012-09-12,17:21:05,kair103,,,,
limGru,2012-10-19,09:45:03,kair028,,,,
limGru,2012-10-19,09:45:06,kair028,,,,
limGru,2012-10-19,09:45:14,kair028,,,,
gru,207,BNP50E,bnp 50 equity,1,01,Gestore 01
limGru,2012-09-13,11:49:58,kair022,,,,
limGru,2012-10-05,15:20:11,kair048,,,,
limGru,2012-10-17,09:23:14,kair048,,,,
```

and i would import only the rows that begin with "limGru".

Any idea in how to implement my task?

EDITED: please note that the rows have different number of columns, depending on the first filed ("gru" or "limGru")

EDITED 2: Please also take a look here:

[SSIS =- How to process an CSV input file with a variable number of columns based on record type (Header, Detail, Trailer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294563/ssis-how-to-process-an-csv-input-file-with-a-variable-number-of-columns-based)

Comment: do you have access to the table once it is made from the import?

Comment: @Pow-Ian: yes, the table is in my database

Comment: I was going to suggest that once the table is loaded just delete all rows Where first column = gru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all data from the flat file and then use the conditional split transformation.
If you're not familiar with the transformation follow the link below:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem. The input file has a different number of columns, depending on the record type. I must first import the whole file in a single-column table?

Comment: Can you edit your original question with a very simple example of this, I'm not entirely sure what you mean and would need a better understanding of your process and what you are trying to achieve for the final output.

Comment: Hi Debura, what I would to achieve is to import in a SQL table, splitted field by filed, only the rows that begin with "limGru".

Comment: OK I understand now, my original suggestion is correct you don't have a different number of columns, each row has the same number of columns but those with 'limgru' have null values for the final four columns, that's fine. You can drop those extra columns from the source at any time using the mappings tab in the transformation options. Almost all transformations have mappings so you can choose which columns you persist in the data flow. The other good thing about using the split is the rows which have only 'gru' can be easily funnelled to another destination if you ever need it :)

Comment: Hi @Debura, thanks for your comment. But I need the rows with the extra columns. My question is very simple: it's possible at run-time open the flat file and choose row-by-row if import or discard?

Comment: OK, so you want to import the four empty columns from the flat file, that's not a problem just keep them in the data flow. And the answer is still yes, using the conditional split you can select only the rows that meet a condition, in this case the first column must contain 'limgru'

Answer (score 0):

If `limGru` is fixed value? If so then you can do [Conditional split](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) with condition `[NameOfYourFirstColumn] == "limGru"`